# IBM Cloud Security Advisor

Tags: cloud

It looks like the IBM Cloud Security Advisor is available in the Dallas region. Does this mean that the Security Advisor dashboard will show only findings from certificates and containers from the Dallasregion?

Answer (score 0):

You've pretty much nailed it. Because IBM Cloud Security Advisor is currently available in Dallas only, it will display only Dallas information. More regions coming soon...